# Connect to BLE device with HTML 5 without scanning first

Tags: html, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

For users who struggled with the basics, this is what I learned:

1. Bluetooth on HTML 5 works only in Chrome/Edge: Mozilla and Safari both officially said they won't implement it due to security/privacy reasons (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice#browser_compatibility)
2. It only works with HTTPS or localhost. If it doesn't seem to work, be sure you are connected to a secure server. HTTP won't work.
3. For security reason, any bluetooth scanning/connecting operation must be triggered by the user, so you must link it to e.g. a button press
4. This is the basic code to scan for ALL devices (remember to call this upon a button click for example):

```
function requestDevice() {
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
      acceptAllDevices: true
    })
    .then(device => {
       print(`Connected!`)
    }
  )}
```

If you already know for example the name(s) of your device, you can filter by the name, so you will ONLY see those with that name:

```
function requestDevice() {
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
      acceptAllDevices: false,
      filters: [
        { name: 'MyLovedBLEDevice'}
      ]
    })
    .then(device => {
       print(`Connected!`)
    }
  )}
```

Now my question is... If I know that I want to connect to that device name, every time... And if there are two, ok, doesn't matter, the first or a random one, as long as it's called like that...
Click, and (if it's available of course) it's connected.
Is it at all possible?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Web Bluetooth at all, but regarding all other BLE platforms this question was asked before on StackOverflow. The answer was almost always that scanning is required before making a connection. Would be a surprise to me to see Web Bluetooth work differently

Comment: Thanks. I have seen them but I never found the ones other than 'almost'. Most of the posts are fairly old especially considering that these things progress fast...